# One expression on top of another on the same line and both the same size

Tags: latex

I want to write Vs -> (V1 -> X1 V2 -> X2) but with the V2 -> X2 underneath V1 -> X1.  Is that possible?  Overset won't work, since it alters the top expression. I have look around Stackoverflow a lot and cannot find an answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found one way to do it.

```
\[

\overset{\displaystyle V_{1} \longrightarrow X_{1}} {V_{2} \longrightarrow X_{2}} \qquad    

\]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `\genfrac` construction to set fraction-like expressions:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\topbot}{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}}

\begin{document}

\[
  V_s \rightarrow \biggl( \topbot{V_1 \longrightarrow X_1}{V_2 \longrightarrow X_2} \biggr)
\]

\end{document}
```

`\genfrac` takes five arguments to create a structure (from the [`amsmath` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf); section **4.11.3 The `\genfrac` command**, p 14):

> The last two correspond to `\frac`’s numerator and denominator; the
>   first two are optional delimiters [...]; the third is a line thickness
>   override [0 implies an invisible rule]; and the fourth argument is a
>   mathstyle override: integer values 0-3 select respectively
>   `\displaystyle`, `\textstyle`, `\scriptstyle`, and
>   `\scriptscriptstyle`. If the third argument is left empty, the line
>   thickness defaults to ‘normal’.

Not sure whether your use of `(`...`)` is intentional in the question. If they are *always* included in the use of your construction you could define

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\topbot}{\genfrac(){0pt}{}}
```

instead.